# How can use rustls to authenticate my connection to a postgres database in Rust?

Tags: postgresql, rust, tls1.3

I want to use a cert in my Windows certificate store, to connect to a postgres database with TLS. I'm agnostic about which libraries to use. It looks like `rustls` is the best way to deal with the TLS side, but I can't see how to connect it with either the `postgres` crate or `diesel`.